# Inserting rows in Excel and filling them with certain dataframe values using Openpyxl, Python, and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm new to Python and coding, and I'm trying to use Openpyxl to insert new lines in a workbook and then fill them with certain data from my dataframe.

Here's my dataframe:

| Country | Fact | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Algeria | Population | 43m |
| Algeria | Capital | Algiers |
| Algeria | Language | Arabic |
| Algeria | Rating | 80% |
| Algeria | Crime rate | 53.82 |
| Albania | Birth Rate | 2.9 |
| Spain | Language | Spanish |
| Spain | Population | 47m |

The Country_Facts workbook is laid out as follows:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **America** |  |
| Population | 329m |
| Capital | Washington DC |
| **Algeria** |  |
| **Belgium** |  |
| Capital | Brussels |
| Language | French |

So I need to insert lines after Algeria and then add the section related to Algeria and Albania.

My code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Country_Facts.xlsx')

for Country in df:
    if df[Country] == "Algeria":
        ws.insert_rows()

# Then I want to fill each inserted row with values from df['Fact', 'Amount]
```

To give this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| **America** |  |
| Population | 329m |
| Capital | Washington DC |
| **Algeria** |  |
| Population | 43m |
| Capital | Algiers |
| Language | Arabic |
| Rating | 80% |
| Crime Rate | 53.82 |
| **Albania** |  |
| Birth Rate | 2.9 |
| **Belgium** |  |
| Capital | Brussels |
| Language | French |
| **Spain** |  |
| Language | Spanish |
| Population | 47m |

But I'm stuck at this point.

I could also iterate over rows in the dataframe, but I've read on other Stack Overflow answers that you shouldn't iterate over rows of dataframes. If I turned the data into strings rather than a data frame I could then iterate over each row. Like below, but I still struggle with inserting data from the *Fact* and *Amount* column.

```
words = "Algeria"

for r_idx, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(max_row=ws.max_row, max_col=3)):
    if ws.cell(r_idx+1, 1).value in words:
        for row in wb:
            ws.insert_rows()
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you iterate over dataframe rows? Openpyxl has a function **specifically** for doing this.

Comment: Hi Charlie! I read it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas  and I'd iterate over the dataframe to see country name and add rows to the Country_Facts file. I updated the question to include the output I'm looking for.

Comment: I think what you want to do can be done using "stacking" in Pandas, but you can do it in openpyxl. However, you probably want to read up on using `ws.iter_rows()` as you shouldn't need an enumerator or call `ws.cell()` inside the loop.

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for your help! I haven't worked it out yet but I did do a workaround. I created a shell file with the facts column in my example data and then used map to populate the values. (My data is similar to my example, though I just realised I repeated elements in the Fact column, in my data the fact column elements are unique allowing me to map them to the shell file.)